# Accumulation point of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$X \not= \emptyset$,$Y \not= \emptyset$,$(X,T)$ and $(Y,V)$ are topological space. Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ function is a homeomorphizm and $A \subseteq X $ if $x \in X $ is a accumulation point of $A$ show that $f(x)$ is a accumulation point of $f(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Given any open neighbourhood $U$ of $f(x)$ you need to show that there is at least a point $a\in A$ such that $a\neq x$ and $f(a)\in U$. This is enough, since the fact that $f$ is invertible guarantees that $f(a)\neq f(x)$ and by definition $f(a)\in f(A)$.

$f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open set in $X$ and it contains $x$. Since $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$, we can find a point $a$ in $f^{-1}(U)\cap A$ such that $a\neq x$. By construction we have that $f(a)\in f(A)\cap U$.

Notice that you may weaken the hypothesis, $f$ does not need to be an homeomorphism, it is enough if it is a continuous invertible map.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be any subset of $X$. We shall prove thet $f(A')\subset (f(A))'$, where for every subset $S$ of $X$, $S'$ will denote the set of all accumulation points of $S$.

Let $x\in f(A')$. Then $f^{-1}(x)\in A'$, so $f^{-1}(x)$ is an accumulation point of $A$. So, for all neighborhoods $U$ in $X$ of $f^{-1}(x)$ we have that
$$A\cap U- \{f^{-1}(x)\}\neq\varnothing$$
Consequently, 
$$f(A)\cap f(U)- \{x\}\neq\varnothing$$
Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, and $U$ is an open subset of $X$, we have that $f(U)$ is an open subset of $Y$. Moreover, every open subset of $Y$ is of the form $f(U)$ for some open subset $U$ of $X$, because $f$ is a bijection. Therefore $x$ is an accumulation point of $f(A)$, that is $x\in (f(A))'$. Therefore,
$$f(A')\subset (f(A))'$$